# How do I efficiently move a searched set of Gmail conversations into another label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

- I have searched my emails, let say `From: Joe.bloggs`
- I have a list of results
- I highlight some mails
- I want to press "v" which allows me to type a label to move them to

However that shortcut doesn't work.

Then I see the move icon is replaced by "move to inbox", however most of the messages are in the inbox already.

The only way I can see, it to find the label (among thousands) and drag, or use the labels icon, and then archive afterwards, which is far less efficient.

Move should work with a filtered list of messages, no?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one or more emails selected, by either use of a query or a label or just checking boxes you have the following options.

- Move to inbox. This takes all the selected messages/conversations and attaches the inbox label to those items.
- Use the label pull down. This will attach labelx to all the emails. If they already have a label then labelx will  be added to the ones attached to the message.
- The label pull down places at  the top of the list any labels that are currently in attached to any of your selected emails. This can be used to remove certain labels from those messages if they no longer apply.
- Under More you can find the archive command. This strips the inbox label from the selected emails. If no selected emails have the inbox label attached, then this command under more will not appear.

So to add labelx to all the selected emails and archive all the messages only takes 2 commands:

1. Labels:labelx;
2. More:Archive;

Comment: Yes, I put this in my question.  You can do label + archive.  However my point is that you can do "move" normally, and not from a search, so you have to remember that you're in a search and use a different workflow accordingly.  This is just very inefficient, I'm constantly doing it the wrong way, when it should be the same way "I want to move this mail"